# How to restart the spring boot application in the middle of endpoint and then start executing from there?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, writetofile, application-restart

I want to restart the spring boot application while I am in middle of an endpoint method

Lets consider this example:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/CreateView")
    public ResponseView createView()
    {
//      Here I write something to one of my files at runtime

//          //some more code
//      -------> SOMEWHERE I WANT THE SPRING BOOT APPLICATION TO RESTART<---------
//      And here I want to access those new writing (via reflection) that I have done at the runtime

    }
```

Is there any way to do the above?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have tried this dependency but that doesnt help

Comment: You can't restart in the middle of execution. It would be like sawing off the branch you're sitting on. Take a step back and re-think what you're doing. --- This question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), and you're trying to solve your real problem the wrong way, so maybe if you explain what it is you're *really* trying to do, we might help you find another way of accomplishing that.

Comment: oh okay, my bad !! My problem is exactly the same as I stated above, I want the changes to be read !! Should I create different API calls for it and in between restarting the application? Or is there any better way available?

Comment: What changes? What are you writing? How is that used when starting the app?

Comment: Actually I am writing some methods at run time to a java file and later I am traversing through all the methods in that file via reflection.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question, explaining in detail what you trying to do, because dynamic creation of classes from non-framework code is a huge code smell.